# App engine Java application only runs on F instance?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I tried to deploy a spring java 11 application to GCP app engine, on a B2 instance, and it deploys but immediately crashes with this singular error:

```
textPayload: "[start] 2021/06/20 18:09:58.614416 Start program failed: termination triggered by nginx exit"
```

So I tried again this time on an F instance, and it works perfectly. Does app engine B instance not support Java or something? Im reading the documentation and it seems like it should work. I tried again with the B instance changing only my app.yaml file, and it crashes again and throws me the same error. Is there some unwritten documentation on the differences between the F and B instances?

For reference just in case here is my app.yaml when trying both F and B instances:

B instance:

```
runtime: java11
env: standard 
instance_class: B2 
service: hello-there 
basic_scaling: 
    max_instances: 2 
    idle_timeout: 10m
```

F instance:

```
runtime: java11
env: standard 
instance_class: F4 
service: hello-there 
automatic_scaling: 
    max_instances: 1
```

[image: stack trace]

```
I did more attempts and i captured the tail log here:
2021-06-20 01:52:08 ho-api[1]
2021-06-20 01:52:08 ho-api[1]    .   ____          _            __ _ _
2021-06-20 01:52:08 ho-api[1]   /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
2021-06-20 01:52:08 ho-api[1]  ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
2021-06-20 01:52:08 ho-api[1]   \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
2021-06-20 01:52:08 ho-api[1]    '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
2021-06-20 01:52:08 ho-api[1]   =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
2021-06-20 01:52:08 ho-api[1]   :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.1)
2021-06-20 01:52:08 ho-api[1]
2021-06-20 01:52:08 ho-api[1]  2021-06-20 01:52:08.180  INFO 11 -.
```

.
.
.
.
.
.

```
 : Started Hello in 10.229 seconds (JVM running for 11.56)
Default
2021-06-20 15:09:58.513 ADT
I0620 18:09:46.223078 20 jvmti_agent.cc:159] Java debuglet initialization started
Default
2021-06-20 15:09:58.521 ADT
I0620 18:09:46.224159 20 jvmti_agent.cc:193] Java debuglet initialization completed
Default
2021-06-20 15:09:58.521 ADT
I0620 18:09:46.370362 20 jvmti_agent.cc:204] Java VM started
Default
2021-06-20 15:09:58.521 ADT
I0620 18:09:46.395424 20 jvmti_agent.cc:214] JvmtiAgent::JvmtiOnVMInit initialization time: 25084 microseconds
Default
2021-06-20 15:09:58.522 ADT
I0620 18:09:46.396665 29 jvmti_agent_thread.cc:95] Agent thread started: CloudDebugger_main_worker_thread
Default
2021-06-20 15:09:58.522 ADT
I0620 18:09:46.400967 29 jvm_internals.cc:370] Loading internals from /opt/cdbg/cdbg_java_agent_internals.jar
Default
2021-06-20 15:09:58.522 ADT
I0620 18:09:46.558127 29 jvmti_agent.cc:365] Initializing Cloud Debugger Java agent version: 2.27
Default
2021-06-20 15:09:58.522 ADT
I0620 18:09:46.559283 29 jni_logger.cc:31] Initializing ClassPathLookup, default classpath: true, extra classpath: []
Default
2021-06-20 15:09:58.522 ADT
I0620 18:09:46.576998 29 jni_logger.cc:31] Total size of indexed resources database: 3679 bytes
Default
2021-06-20 15:09:58.522 ADT
I0620 18:09:46.582134 29 jvm_internals.cc:131] ClassPathLookup constructor time: 23965 microseconds
Default
2021-06-20 15:09:58.522 ADT
I0620 18:09:46.582628 29 yaml_data_visibility_config_reader.cc:67] debugger-blocklist.yaml was not found. Using default settings.
Default
2021-06-20 15:09:58.523 ADT
I0620 18:09:48.015766 29 jni_logger.cc:31] Debuggee gcp:378392885568:15c098d156eb62e2, agentId 60ce1323-0000-2bc4-944e-582429bcf920, registered: {"debuggee":{"id":"gcp:378392885568:15c098d156eb62e2","project":"378392885568","uniquifier":"DA39A3EE5E6B4B0D3255BFEF95601890AFD80709","description":"owl-system-ho-api-1-435996213358003587","agentVersion":"google.com/java-gcp/@2","sourceContexts":[{"git":{"url":"https://github.com/owl-fullDev/HOapi.git","revisionId":"373d818bb1c2436ac0ba0689712a621f33c748e8"}}],"labels":{"version":"1","module":"ho-api","minorversion":"435996213358003587","blocklistsource":"none"}},"agentId":"60ce1323-0000-2bc4-944e-582429bcf920"}, agent version: 2.27
Default
2021-06-20 15:09:58.523 ADT
I0620 18:09:48.015808 29 jvmti_agent.cc:437] Attaching Java debuglet
Default
2021-06-20 15:09:58.523 ADT
I0620 18:09:48.018111 29 rate_limit.cc:137] CPU count: 2
Default
2021-06-20 15:09:58.523 ADT
I0620 18:09:48.018128 29 rate_limit.cc:145] Adjusted CPU count: 1
Default
2021-06-20 15:09:58.523 ADT
I0620 18:09:48.018142 29 debugger.cc:100] Initializing Java debuglet
Default
2021-06-20 15:09:58.523 ADT
I0620 18:09:48.030673 29 debugger.cc:109] Debugger::Initialize initialization time: 13 ms
Default
2021-06-20 15:09:58.524 ADT
I0620 18:09:58.406167 58 jvmti_agent.cc:222] Java VM termination
Default
2021-06-20 15:09:58.524 ADT
I0620 18:09:58.407428 29 jvmti_agent_thread.cc:99] Agent thread exited: CloudDebugger_main_worker_thread
Default
2021-06-20 15:09:58.524 ADT
I0620 18:09:58.415417 58 worker.cc:113] Debugger threads terminated
Default
2021-06-20 15:09:58.524 ADT
I0620 18:09:58.415448 58 jvmti_agent.cc:236] JvmtiAgent::JvmtiOnVMDeath cleanup time: 9298 microseconds
Default
2021-06-20 15:09:58.615 ADT
[start] 2021/06/20 18:09:58.614416 Start program failed: termination triggered by nginx exit
```

Comment: Were there more details in the logs?

Comment: For some reason no, GCP seems to not detect this as an error. I attached a screenshot of the logs. It seems to work fine until it exits on its own.

Comment: Did you try to listen on the PORT env var instead of  8080 with B instance class?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere just tried that, removed the port 8080 warning and changed the error but still the crashes.

Comment: nginx crash.. Do you try to add special runtime file, to override nginx App Engine config? Or do you have only java standard file? Did you also implmenet _warmup endpoint or not?

Comment: The shutdown process may have been triggered because the instance exceeds the maximum memory. Could you try upgrading your B instance to B4 and see if the problem persists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After re-reading the app engine documentation, I found the following line deep inside the lifecycle.

> Startup Each service instance is created in response to a start
> request, which is an empty HTTP GET request to /_ah/start.

The app needs to respond with a HTTP code 200, only then will app engine allow the app to keep running, if anything other than 200 is returned, it will kill the app. My application requires an auth header, so it was returning 401's, which caused app engine to kill the instance. This is only for B instances, not F instances. So the solution was to whitelist the default endpoint from authentication.

Comment: wow, this worked, I cannot believe how stupid this is :D

`web.ignoring().antMatchers("/_ah/start");` in the SecurityConfig

Comment: It would be nice if this was on the documentation about B instances

Comment: It´s a bit hidden but here it is the doc
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java-gen2/how-instances-are-managed

Comment: This saved my day, or maybe even my week. To be honest, this quite obvious but still not. Thanks for sharing the solution.